# Label Management

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, sql-server-2016

I'm designing a system and would like to have labels for some of my columns that are managed in one location and that constraints are in place to ensure that any labels in use are listed in the Labels table.  What is the best way to accomplish this?

What I'm working with right now is a table called [Labels] with columns for [Group], [ID], and [Title], where [Group] refers to a group of entries sharing the same [Group] value, [ID] refers to a unique label in that group, and [Title] is the human friendly value that will be used by the application.  However, I'm at a loss on how to constrain the values as foreign key constraints don't seem to take static values.  Perhaps I'm missing something simple...

**Example Query:**

```
SELECT [Labels].[Title] 
FROM [EventList] 
INNER JOIN [Labels] ON [Labels].[ID] = [EventList].[Status] AND [Labels].[Group] = 'Event Status'
```

**Example Foreign Key Constraint:**

```
ALTER TABLE [EventList]
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EventList_Labels
FOREIGN KEY ('Event Status',[Status])
REFERENCES Labels([Group],[ID])
```

**Label Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE Labels
(
[Group] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
[ID] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
[Title] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
)
```

**Example Label Data**

```
'Event Status',1,'Planning'
'Event Status',2,'Completed'
'Event Type',1,'Public'
'Event Type',2','Private'
'Employee Status',1,'Active'
...
```

Server in use is Microsoft SQL Server Standard 2016.

Thanks in advance for any help, pointers, or recommendations.

Comment: Sounds like some design issues are happening here. Of course you can't use a string literal as a foreign key. That is not how a foreign key works at all. Can you share the DDL for the Labels table also?

Comment: @SeanLange Updated question to include labels table example.

Comment: Oh I had a feeling it was going to be this type of thing. This is a challenge because your Labels table holds all the different types of Labels. You will need to use a function with a constraint (not a foreign key) to ensure that the label is the right type. I would prefer to see a better key on your Labels table. The best you can do is have a composite key with Group and ID. Even with that you would need a function because just the key isn't enough in your case because there are keys that are not valid.

Comment: The [one table to rule them all](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58372/is-the-one-description-table-to-rule-them-all-approch-good) discussion is a good starting point.